# Cannot build wheel for cryptography

Tags: raspberry-pi, cryptography

Why is openssl not found?
I am using using updated Raspbian 11 , pip , python3-dev and   openssl , rustc.

Here are logs:

```
    error: ***could not find system library 'openssl'*** required by the 'openssl-sys' crate
```

...
error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module --crate-type cdylib --` failed with code 101
[end of output]

....
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography

Comment: Most likely the openssl library is missing. Try `apt install libssl-dev`.

Comment: Thanks, i ran that. 
Now it hangs in :Installing dependencies from lock file
Should I let it sit, or reboot ?

  • Updating certifi (2023.7.22 -> 2022.12.7): Pending...
  • Updating charset-normalizer (3.2.0 -> 2.1.1): Pending...
  • Installing markupsafe (2.1.2): Pending...
  • Installing pytz (2023.3): Pending...
  • Updating urllib3 (1.26.16 -> 1.26.14): Pending...
  • Updating zipp (3.16.2 -> 3.11.0): Pending...